# Social media MYSQL database design

Tags: mysql

I am project managing the creation of a social network for our senior Software development class, and have a question about the efficiency of database queries.

The database needs to; store login details for each user, settings, all of each users posts, each users friends

So the design that i am currently thinking of (and would like suggestions as to a better way) is:

A database that contains all users login details, a seperate database for each user (so that theoretically they can be moved to other drives i.e. symlinks) that contails all their personal details and posts.

Thats all pretty straightforward but in the generation of the 'newsfeed' equivalent querying that many databases to find recent posts would not be feasible, so i was thinking that each user's database contains a table that contains links to other users posts identical to a chronological display of a 'newsfeed'. and that each of these tables is appended to whenever a user on your friends list posts.

This idea seems woefully inefficient and i was wondering what the proper way of approaching this problem would be?

And yes i am aware that in small scall application performance differences would be negligible but its the principle that i am looking for.

Comment: I would recommend googling "database graph theory"

Comment: what do you mean by "a separate database for each user"?

Comment: Is your class going to grade you on the sanity of developing enterprise scale applications before proof of concept? What's wrong with a basic relational database structure until you see a valid cause for scaling up to even read/write servers, never mind individual databases for each user?

Comment: do you think the graph style database would be more suited to this problem?

Comment: i believe its on the theoretical performance of the system, how would you suggest an effiecient way of generating the 'newsfeed'